# Shortest string with lowest edit distance from set of strings

Tags: string, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

Suppose I have a list of strings, which are similar. I wish to figure out the common part or characteristic of all these strings. Is there a known way to figure out a string which is most similar to all strings in a given set, and does not belong to the set?

For example, if I have the following set:

```
Hello
Hell
Help
Hepl
```

'Hel' gives a levenshtein distance of 2,1,1,1. Currently I am thinking of taking different substrings as base, and computing the distance (my sets are fairly small, so brute forcing will not be an issue), but this solution does not find strings which are not essentially substrings of any given string in the set, but might be the most optimal solution (cases like where the solution is conjugation of two substrings).

Any leads regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: I have never had to code this, but [Jaro–Winkler distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance)

Comment: "Hell" is better than "Hel" since the former gives Levenstein distances of 1,1,1,1.

Comment: Try multiple alignment using the clustal algorithm with a flat letter matrix (?) and fiddle with gap penalties.

Comment: @GuyCoder : Jaro Winkler might substitute Levenshtein as the distance metric, but the problem at hand is to come up with strings to consider, and how to evaluate the best one.

Comment: @user31264 : True, but we do not want a string which is already present in our set. And "Hell" actually gives 1,0,1,1.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean : Never heard of this before, but a little bit of googling tells me I can give it a go. Will try that and share the results with you!

Answer (score 1):

You said brute force is acceptable :-). The classic approach then is breadth first search. For each string in your list you generate all strings with an edit distance of 1. from those you do all distance 2 strings and so on. for every given string you get a tree of mutated strings. After every round (distance) you check if there is a string common to every tree.

pseudocode for a levenshtein distance:

```
alphabet = "abcd..."
starters = "Hello", "Hell", "Help", "Hepl"
relatives = set()
distance = 0
for word in starters
    trees[word][distance] = word

while len(relatives) == 0
    distance++
    for tree in trees
        for word in tree[distance-1]
            for pos in range(len(word))
                new_word = word.erase(pos)
                if new_word not in tree
                    tree[distance].insert(new_word)
                    dict[new_word] += 1
                    if dict[new_word] == len(starters)
                        relatives.insert(new_word)
            for pos in range(len(word))
                for letter in alphabet
                    new_word = word.replace(pos, letter)
                    if new_word not in tree:
                        tree[distance].insert(new_word)
                        dict[new_word] += 1
                        if dict[new_word] == len(starters)
                            relatives.insert(new_word)
            for pos in range(len(word) + 1):
                for letter in alphabet
                    new_word = word.insert(pos, letter)
                    if new_word not in tree
                        tree[distance].insert(new_word)
                        dict[new_word] += 1
                        if dict[new_word] == len(starters)
                            relatives.insert(new_word)
print relatives
```

Comment: Pretty neat solution. The only caveat is that if my strings are of large lengths, and the common string is small, this will take forever to find the solution. Will see if I can somehow think of optimizing such cases.

Comment: @Ulrich: It was you who said brute force is acceptable :-). If this is about DNA strings you got a nice pointer from Malcolm. What is the string length? Why is the common string small? Please refine your question to represent your actual requirements.